# Dynamically add columns to temp table as column name comes as feild value of another tabl

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have one physical table, in which I can select a field value using select fieldvalue from the table. I need those resultant field values as columns of a temptable and another fieldvalue as corresponding column value based on fieldvalue.

eg: select KeyField, ValueFile from phytable

suppose KeyField X,Y,Z  ValueFileld is A,B,C correspondingly X->A

I need Temp table with X,Y,Z comes as column names of temptable and A,B,C comes as row values of corresponding column.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will really help us help you. Also, what have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Considering the tags, however, if you are looking for a dynamic pivot, there are plenty of examples on Stack Overflow. [\[sql-server\] Dynamic Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+Dynamic+Pivot)

Comment: Do you really need a temp table?
If you just need the results of the pivot then follow the link from Lamu
Otherwise do the same and just add a step to store the results of the pivot into a temp table

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same using dynamic query .

Steps followed

- insert the field values to temp table
- looping through temp table
- fetch each column 1 by one
- inside loop write alter table add column statement for New Temp table

  //-------Query Snippet --------//

  ```
  SELECT Name into #ControlTable FROM Tbl_A
  WHILE exists (SELECT [Name] FROM #ControlTable)
  BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1 @columnname=[Name] FROM #ControlTable
  @alterqry="ALTER TABLE Tbl_B Add column '+@columnname+' varchar(50)"
  EXECUTE(@alterqry)
  DELETE FROM #ControlTable WHERE [Name]=@columnname
  END
  ```